# Warning from Facebook about pre-filled captions

Tags: facebook-sharer, caption, x-facebook-platform, facebook-stream-story

We just got the following message from Facebook

> It looks like your app, XXXXXXXX may be posting photos with pre-filled
>   captions. If that's the case, you'll want to remove any default photo
>   captions within the next few days in order to avoid restrictions.

[Our users write a post like this](http://blog.tynerpondfarm.com/blog/sustainable-farm-journey/re-training-pigs-to-wire-in-the-woods-questions?utm_medium=compendium&utm_campaign=Re%3a%20training%20pigs%20to%20wire%20in%20the%20woods%20questions&utm_content=admin&utm_source=facebook&fbnonce=1917015399) Then we allow them to share the post to Facebook as a shared link or a photo. [Here is an example of one of our image posts.](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=606600692708133&set=a.398808190154052.97524.342567919111413&type=1&permPage=1)

We do pre-fill the caption with the title of the post, but that was manually generated by the user previously in the workflow and seems to [follow their guidelines here.](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#integration)

Does anybody have prior experience with this and have any clue as to what we can change so that we don't get our app restricted?  We are trying to be good citizens, and I think we are. I think we managed to trigger some sort of auto detection on Facebook's side and it doesn't look like there is anybody we can contact resolve this situation.

Comment: Where does the user type the bit.ly link?

Comment: @Igy The entire caption is editable. It defaults to the Title + the bit.ly. The encoded bit.ly link is comprised of hostname, a path prefix (configured at setup), and a slug (defined by the user when the post is created), plus extra tracking ga params as configured by the user.